# How do I present a View Controller with UIView, UIButton sub-classes?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

So I have created this UIButton Sub-class. It's a reusable component and can be added in any view controller. I need to present an alert view controller with the tap in the button. So basically I need to find out in which view controller the button lies so I can pass a view controller as a parameter.

```
final class ProfileButton: UIButton {

let picker = UIImagePickerController()

lazy var shadowImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "download")
    return imageView
}()

override public init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupSelf()
    self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(profileButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
}
override public func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    shadowImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.width/2.70
    shadowImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
}

@objc func profileButtonTapped(){
    imageHandler(presenter: )
}

@objc func imageHandler(presenter: UIViewController!){
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Profile Picture", message: "Please select your profile picture", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        print("I am working")
    })
    let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        print("I am working")
    })

    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    alertController.addAction(cameraAction)
    presenter.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I actually need to find out the view controller so I can pass it in the imageHandler(presenter: UIViewController) function.

Comment: Why don't you do the `addTarget(selector:)` in your view controller?

Comment: If I have let's say 20 view controllers that creates this object. It won't make sense to addTarget in each view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can get the top controller using this extension

```
extension UIApplication {

    class func getTopMostViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
        if var topController = keyWindow?.rootViewController {
            while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
                topController = presentedViewController
            }
            return topController
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}


@objc func imageHandler() {
        //...
        UIApplication.getTopMostViewController()?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `weak var` reference to the controller inside your `UIButton`. Better way would be add the handler function in the `UIViewController` extension and `addTarget` in the `viewDidLoad` instead of the UIButton's `init(frame:)`. Here's an example:

```
final class ProfileButton: UIButton {
    //Remove addTarget from init(frame:)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let profileButton = ProfileButton()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //...
        profileButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(imageHandler), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}

extension UIViewController {

    @objc func imageHandler() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Profile Picture", message: "Please select your profile picture", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            print("I am working")
        })
        let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            print("I am working")
        })

        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        alertController.addAction(cameraAction)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew this method. However the profileButton sublclass  is supposed to be a separate entity that is supposed to do the work. So had to do the other way.